# MongoDb writeMany or None

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a mongo database. I need to implement a function which will use `updateMany` to update multiple documents. But I want to rollback all the changes if there is error in any one of the documents. 
I have read about write concerns but I am not sure how can i achieve this.

Comment: You may find your answer here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

Comment: @Michael thanks, I was not much educated in the concepts of transactions, but I think this will do. thanks